# FALSE message when trying to change number format

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print my numbers with 2 decimal places so trying to insert this code .NumberFormat = "0.00". However when I do this I get a FALSE message.

This is my code which works (but with wrong formatting)

```
Sub print_misc_test()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iter As Long
    Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Columns(28).ClearContents
    With Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template")
        lastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        iter = 2
        For Each cell In .Range("AB2:" & "AB" & lastRow)
            cell.Value = .Range("B" & iter) & "|" & .Range("C" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("D" & iter) & "|" & .Range("E" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("F" & iter) & "|" & .Range("G" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("H" & iter) & "|" & .Range("I" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("J" & iter) & "|" & .Range("L" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("M" & iter) & "|" & .Range("N" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("O" & iter) & "|" & .Range("P" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("Q" & iter) & "|" & .Range("R" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("S" & iter) & "|" & .Range("U" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("V" & iter) & "|" & .Range("W" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("X" & iter) & "|" & .Range("Y" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("Z" & iter) & "|" & .Range("AA" & iter)
            iter = iter + 1
         Next
     End With
End Sub
```

So with the following code I get FALSE

```
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim iter As Long
    Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template").Columns(28).ClearContents
    With Sheets("1099-Misc_Form_Template")
        lastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        iter = 2
        For Each cell In .Range("AB2:" & "AB" & lastRow)
            cell.Value = .Range("B" & iter) & "|" & .Range("C" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("D" & iter) & "|" & .Range("E" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("F" & iter) & "|" & .Range("G" & iter).numberFormat = 
             "0.00" & "|" & _
            .Range("H" & iter) & "|" & .Range("I" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("J" & iter) & "|" & .Range("L" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("M" & iter) & "|" & .Range("N" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("O" & iter) & "|" & .Range("P" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("Q" & iter) & "|" & .Range("R" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("S" & iter) & "|" & .Range("U" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("V" & iter) & "|" & .Range("W" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("X" & iter) & "|" & .Range("Y" & iter) & "|" & _
            .Range("Z" & iter) & "|" & .Range("AA" & iter)
            iter = iter + 1
         Next
     End With
End Sub
```

I would like to have my numbers shown as 2 decimal places in column AB

Comment: Use `Format`. `.Range("G" & iter).numberFormat = "0.00"` is a logical statement.

Comment: So it should be ```range("G" & iter).format?```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Format`. `.Range("G" & iter).numberFormat = "0.00"` is a logical statement that is evaluated, and its *result*, namely `FALSE`, is concatenated with everything else.

```
... & Format(.Range("G" & iter).Value, "0.00") ...
```